# Alternative to CSS only onclick function

Tags: javascript, css

Alternative to CSS only onclick functioni.html

When you click on any of the tabs it will kick you straight to the start of the tab menu. I cannot use javascript or jquery so cannot use onclick="false". Is there a CSS way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: it jumps to the anchors because their href attributes are pointed at them. you'd have to modify the HTML.

Comment: Why can't you use javascript?

Comment: it is on ebay and ebay do not allow javascript, iframes or jquery

Comment: @jbabey so is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having stems from your use of the CSS `:target` selector (which requires the `#item-1` in the URL to function). Setting `href="#item-1"` allows the `:target` selector to function at the cost of putting `#item-1` in the URL, which is what causes the page to jump. It's a vicious catch-22 and there's no way around it using `href` attributes.

The only way I know how to duplicate tab functionality using only CSS is to use a variation of ["the checkbox hack"](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhDQ/1/) (substituting radio buttons for checkboxes).

In essence, use a `<label>Tab</label><input type="radio" />` element set where you are currently using `<a href="">Tab</a>` and then set CSS style rules to control visibility of the tab-content div based on the `checked` property of the radio button.

Specific to your code:

```
input[type=radio] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
   /* For mobile, it's typically better to position radio on top of clickable
      area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
}

/* Default State */
.noint11_menu > li > div {
   display: none;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=radio]:checked ~ div {
   display: block;
}
```

will work when your markup is:

```
<li id="item-1">
    <label for="toggle-Shipping">Shipping</label>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle-Shipping" name="toggleTabs" checked="checked">
    <div>
        <p>Tab Content: Shipping</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="item-2">
    <label for="toggle-Payment">Payment</label>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle-Payment" name="toggleTabs">
    <div>
        <p>Tab Content: Payment</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="item-3">
    <label for="toggle-Returns">Returns</label>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle-Returns" name="toggleTabs">
    <div id="notice">
        <p>Tab Content: Returns</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="item-4">
    <label for="toggle-Tab4">Tab4</label>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle-Tab4" name="toggleTabs">
    <div>
        <p>Tab Content: Tab4</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/ezhDQ/

Please note in the fiddle, I set `<div class="footer">` to be a footer for all tabs, not each tab. This is because your markup uses the `id` attribute for the Facebook, Twitter, Skype, web, and Favorite images. The purpose of the `id` attribute is to identify one specific element on the page (meaning the `id` attribute of each element having one must be unique).

If you want each tab to have its own footer, change your markup to use the `name` attribute instead.

Also, below is your page with completely valid XHTML Transitional markup (which will help in the long run for cross-browser consistency):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/parts.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/handheld.css" media="handheld" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/font.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .noint11_menu > li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    input[type=radio] {
       position: absolute;
       top: -9999px;
       left: -9999px;
       /* For mobile, it's typically better to position radio on top of clickable
          area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
    }

    /* Default State */
    .noint11_menu > li > div {
       display: none;
    }

    /* Toggled State */
    input[type=radio]:checked ~ div {
       display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="full">
        <div id="header100">
            <img id="header" alt="Our Logo" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/ubreakirepairheader.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="noint_box1">
            <table border="0" width="958">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="948" height="27" valign="top" class="content4">
                            <div id="tab2" class="css-tabs">
                                <ul class="noint11_menu">
                                    <li id="item-1">
                                        <label for="toggle-Shipping">Shipping</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Shipping" name="toggleTabs" checked="checked" />
                                        <div>
                                            <p><img id="shippingtable" alt="Shipping Table" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/shippingtable.png" width="684px" height="242px" /></p>
                                            <div class="footer">
                                                <img alt="next section" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/line.png" width="976" height="9" />
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="header3" href="http://contact.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ContactUserNextGen&amp;recipient=irepair">Please click here if you wish to contact us about this product</a>
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="header3">or</p>
                                                <p class="header3">use one of the links below</p>
                                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ubreakirepair">
                                                        <img name="facebook" alt="Visit us on Facebook" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/facebook.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/ubreak_irepair">
                                                    <img name="twitter" alt="Visit us at Twitter" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/Twitter.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="skype:ubreakirepair?chat">
                                                    <img name="skype" alt="Open Skype" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/skype.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/contactus.php">
                                                    <img name="web" alt="Contact Us" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/website.png" style="text-align:center" />
                                                </a>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="http://my.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?AcceptSavedSeller&amp;mode=0&amp;preference=0&amp;sellerid=irepair">
                                                        <img name="fav" alt="Favorite Us at Ebay" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/fav.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="item-2">
                                        <label for="toggle-Payment">Payment</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Payment" name="toggleTabs" />
                                        <div>
                                            <p>Tab Content 2</p>
                                            <div class="footer">
                                                <img alt="next section" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/line.png" width="976" height="9" />
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="header3" href="http://contact.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ContactUserNextGen&amp;recipient=irepair">Please click here if you wish to contact us about this product</a>
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="header3">or</p>
                                                <p class="header3">use one of the links below</p>
                                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ubreakirepair">
                                                        <img name="facebook" alt="Visit us on Facebook" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/facebook.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/ubreak_irepair">
                                                    <img name="twitter" alt="Visit us at Twitter" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/Twitter.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="skype:ubreakirepair?chat">
                                                    <img name="skype" alt="Open Skype" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/skype.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/contactus.php">
                                                    <img name="web" alt="Contact Us" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/website.png" style="text-align:center" />
                                                </a>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="http://my.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?AcceptSavedSeller&amp;mode=0&amp;preference=0&amp;sellerid=irepair">
                                                        <img name="fav" alt="Favorite Us at Ebay" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/fav.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="item-3">
                                        <label for="toggle-Returns">Returns</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Returns" name="toggleTabs" />
                                        <div id="notice">
                                            <p>At uBreakiRepair customer satisfaction is paramount. If any item received,
                                                deemed to be faulty or damaged, it will be replaced or refunded. All repairs
                                                require specialised skill and we do not hold any responsibility for the
                                                damage incured in the course of repairing your device. We offer an installation
                                                service if you are not confident in the repair yourself.</p>
                                            <div class="footer">
                                                <img alt="next section" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/line.png" width="976" height="9" />
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="header3" href="http://contact.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ContactUserNextGen&amp;recipient=irepair">Please click here if you wish to contact us about this product</a>
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="header3">or</p>
                                                <p class="header3">use one of the links below</p>
                                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ubreakirepair">
                                                        <img name="facebook" alt="Visit us on Facebook" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/facebook.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/ubreak_irepair">
                                                    <img name="twitter" alt="Visit us at Twitter" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/Twitter.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="skype:ubreakirepair?chat">
                                                    <img name="skype" alt="Open Skype" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/skype.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/contactus.php">
                                                    <img name="web" alt="Contact Us" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/website.png" style="text-align:center" />
                                                </a>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="http://my.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?AcceptSavedSeller&amp;mode=0&amp;preference=0&amp;sellerid=irepair">
                                                        <img name="fav" alt="Favorite Us at Ebay" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/fav.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="item-4" title="click for Tab 4">
                                        <label for="toggle-Tab4">Tab4</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Tab4" name="toggleTabs" />
                                        <div>
                                            <p>Tab Content 4</p>
                                            <div class="footer">
                                                <img alt="next section" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/line.png" width="976" height="9" />
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="header3" href="http://contact.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ContactUserNextGen&amp;recipient=irepair">Please click here if you wish to contact us about this product</a>
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="header3">or</p>
                                                <p class="header3">use one of the links below</p>
                                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ubreakirepair">
                                                        <img name="facebook" alt="Visit us on Facebook" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/facebook.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/ubreak_irepair">
                                                    <img name="twitter" alt="Visit us at Twitter" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/Twitter.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="skype:ubreakirepair?chat">
                                                    <img name="skype" alt="Open Skype" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/skype.png" />
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/contactus.php">
                                                    <img name="web" alt="Contact Us" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/website.png" style="text-align:center" />
                                                </a>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a href="http://my.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?AcceptSavedSeller&amp;mode=0&amp;preference=0&amp;sellerid=irepair">
                                                        <img name="fav" alt="Favorite Us at Ebay" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/fav.png" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="estimate">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's one way to have a working horizontal tab strip (also in valid XHTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/parts.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/handheld.css" media="handheld" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/font.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    li.noint11_menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 10em;
    }
    input[type=radio] {
       position: absolute;
       top: -9999px;
       left: -9999px;
       /* For mobile, it's typically better to position radio on top of clickable
          area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
    }

    /* Default State */
    li.noint11_menu > div {
       display: none;
    }

    /* Toggled State */
    input[type=radio]:checked ~ div {
        color: #EEE;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 700px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
        font-family: 'MuliLight', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background: #0272A7;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #EDF9FF;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #EDF9FF;
    }

    div.css-tabs ul {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    div.css-tabs ul li {
        float: left;
    }

    div.css-tabs {
        float: left;
    }

    div.footer {
        clear: both;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    div.footer div {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="full">
        <div id="header100">
            <img id="header" alt="Our Logo" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/ubreakirepairheader.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="noint_box1">
            <div id="tab2" class="css-tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li id="item-1" class="noint11_menu">
                        <label for="toggle-Shipping">Shipping</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Shipping" name="toggleTabs" checked="checked" />
                        <div>
                            <p><img id="shippingtable" alt="Shipping Table" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/shippingtable.png" width="684px" height="242px" /></p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-2" class="noint11_menu">
                        <label for="toggle-Payment">Payment</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Payment" name="toggleTabs" />
                        <div>
                            <p>Tab Content 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-3" class="noint11_menu">
                        <label for="toggle-Returns">Returns</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Returns" name="toggleTabs" />
                        <div id="notice">
                            <p>At uBreakiRepair customer satisfaction is paramount. If any item received,
                                deemed to be faulty or damaged, it will be replaced or refunded. All repairs
                                require specialised skill and we do not hold any responsibility for the
                                damage incured in the course of repairing your device. We offer an installation
                                service if you are not confident in the repair yourself.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="item-4" class="noint11_menu" title="click for Tab 4">
                        <label for="toggle-Tab4">Tab4</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="toggle-Tab4" name="toggleTabs" />
                        <div>
                            <p>Tab Content 4</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div class="estimate">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div>
                <img alt="next section" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/line.png" width="976" height="9" />
                <p>
                    <a class="header3" href="http://contact.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ContactUserNextGen&amp;recipient=irepair">Please click here if you wish to contact us about this product</a>
                </p>
                <p class="header3">or</p>
                <p class="header3">use one of the links below</p>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ubreakirepair">
                        <img name="facebook" alt="Visit us on Facebook" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/facebook.png" width="48" />
                    </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/ubreak_irepair">
                    <img name="twitter" alt="Visit us at Twitter" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/Twitter.png" width="48" />
                </a>
                <a href="skype:ubreakirepair?chat">
                    <img name="skype" alt="Open Skype" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/skype.png" width="48" />
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/contactus.php">
                    <img name="web" alt="Contact Us" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/website.png" width="48" />
                </a>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://my.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?AcceptSavedSeller&amp;mode=0&amp;preference=0&amp;sellerid=irepair">
                        <img name="fav" alt="Favorite Us at Ebay" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/fav.png" height="48" />
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, great. I tried to convert to radio buttons myself but was unsuccessful. How would I put the tabs along the top with the blue background, then when clicked out will display the content like my original?

Answer (score -1):

Use a null inline javascript event.

```
<a href="javascript://" ... />
```

Comment: EEEm... you don't understand what? Instead of linking #whatever link to javascript://. I'd try this way before building a huge solution... maybe ebay will accept this...

Answer (score -2):

Add blank targets for your hash location(s) href="#item-1":

```
<a name="item-1"></a>
```

If you add this to the top of your page, when a user clicks on the first tab, it'll go **where this blank target anchor tag is located**.

Do the same for:

```
<a name="item-2"></a>
<a name="item-3"></a>
<a name="item-4"></a>
....
```

I'm not sure which part of the page you have access to but try adding them before your full div tag and see the effect:

```
<a name="item-1"></a>
<a name="item-2"></a>
<a name="item-3"></a>
<a name="item-4"></a>
<div id="full">
```

If these extra tags take up undesirable physical space on your page, hide them with CSS using **display: none**

Does this make sense?

P.S. Your page is missing usual **body** and **head** tags which are part of the usual html page structure  ...AND the closing **/html** tag yes :)

Comment: And missing a `</html>` haha!